# How to test whether button was clicked programmatically?

Tags: playwright-test

I am trying to test whether pressing <kbd>space</kbd> or <kbd>enter</kbd> on an element effectively clicks it.

(The element's parent has a keydown handler which looks out for those keys and calls `event.target.click()`.)

On my test page the element is a `<button>` which doesn't do anything.

I can get Playwright to focus the button and press <kbd>space</kbd>.  But I can't figure out how to test whether this clicked the button.

In my test I tried adding an event handler to the `locator` but Playwright didn't like that.  I then tried adding an event handler to the page but I couldn't get it to fire.

```
test('space when menu is open activates current item', async ({ page }) => {
  // Open the menu
  await page.locator('[data-menu-target="button"]').click()
  let clicked = false
  page.locator('[data-menu-target="menuItem"]').locator('nth=0').once('click', event => {clicked = true})
  await page.keyboard.press('Space')
  await expect(clicked).toBeTruthy()
})
```

Is it possible to test for a programmatic click?

Answer (score 0):

I mostly solved this by changing the `<button>` to an `<a href="#foo">` and checking the page URL:

```
await page.keyboard.press('Space')
await expect(page).toHaveURL(/#foo/)
```